# How to typehint Stream of Streams for highlandjs?

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript-typings, highland.js

I am using typescript@2 and highlandjs library. The typings for highland miss the `mergeWithLimit(n)` function. It:

> Takes a Stream of Streams and merges their values and errors into a
>   single new Stream, limitting the number of unpaused streams that can
>   running at any one time.

Now, this method is not yet typehinted for its [DefinitlyTyped typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/highland/index.d.ts). I tried to add it, yet there is only an `interface Stream<R>` and none for a stream of streams.

Yet how would I create an interface for a stream of streams? I tried defining an interface:

```
interface Stream<Stream<R>> implements Stream<R> {
    mergeWithLimit(n: number): Stream<R>;
}
```

yet it does not compile:

```
365     interface Stream<Stream<R>> implements Stream<R> {
                               ~

index.d.ts(365,28): error TS1005: ',' expected.


365     interface Stream<Stream<R>> implements Stream<R> {
                                  ~

index.d.ts(365,31): error TS1109: Expression expected.


365     interface Stream<Stream<R>> implements Stream<R> {
                                               ~~~~~~

index.d.ts(365,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

How to typehint `mergeWithLimit` properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed typehint it correctly by defining an interface:

```
interface StreamOfStreams<R> extends Stream<Stream<R>> {
    /**
     * Takes a Stream of Streams and merges their values and errors into a single new Stream,
     * limitting the number of unpaused streams that can running at any one time.
     *
     * @id mergeWithLimit
     * @section Streams
     * @name Stream.mergeWithLimit()
     * @api public
     */
    mergeWithLimit(n: number): Stream<R>;
}
```

and we added a map defintion:

```
interface Stream<R> extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
    map<U>(f: (x: R) => U): Stream<U>;
    map<S>(f: (x: R) => Stream<S>): StreamOfStreams<S>;
}
```

This now allows us to correctly typehint `mergeWithLimit(n)` by usage of:

```
myStream.map<YourType>(whatEverTheMapFunction).mergeWithLimit(10)
```